# Should I max mods before selling them to other players

Tags: warframe

I am a new player in Warframe and since I reached rank 2, I can start trading with other players. I know it will take some time before I will have something worth selling but I want to know for future reference.

I've read a few guides online on trading and I checked sites with recommended prices like "wftrading.net", but I still don't know are those prices for a maxed modes or simply dropped ones without any upgrades.

Should I level mods before I sell them?

Also sometimes the same mode have 3/5/10 ranks, how can I determine the highest rank for a mod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in trade chat you can see that players will advertise that they are looking for or selling maxed or unranked mods.

In general, people won't care if you don't rank up a 3 rank mod, but in the larger mods may want to aim for a specific number of points for a build. For this reason, they may be looking for unranked/low-ranked.

On the other hand, fully leveled 10-rank mods can fetch a very high price indeed, as the effort for levelling them can be extreme.

You can tell how many ranks a mod can have by mousing over it, and you should see "pips" at the bottom (see image below, #3). These indicate both how many levels the mod has, and how many are possible.

[image: Warframe Mod - thanks to Warframe Wikia]

Comment: Thanks, I know that the mod rank is at the bottom, but I had few Damaged modes which had smaller amount of ranks and I thought that there are some variations of mods. That's why I asked, but I noticed that they actually say Damaged under mode name.